# Move jscrollpane dragger to to new position after adding new dynamic content

Tags: jquery, jscrollpane

I am using jscrollPane in my project, when I am adding dynamic content by ajax, the scrolling works fine but dragger not moving to new position,I want the dragger moved to new added content. I have the id of new added content. I have tried  with  maintainPosition, and stickToBottom but it doesn't work. I have kept autoReinitialise and  used scroll_to. Please anybody have solution?